# Migrating a Whole old Lowagie PDF generator to iText 7 c#. Creating TOC

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext7

Since in earlier versions of the API existed Anchor object, which should work as a link inside the text, I am trying, looking in many tutorials, for a way of adding a TOC that redirects you from index to the page where the title is.

The thing is I am generating PDFs based on XML Documents, so the TOC will vary depending on XML content.

I have begun iText7 for C# from 0 and thanks to tutorials at itextpdf.com and some stackOverflow tutorials, between many others, I am already able to make almost everything I want, except this. Anyways I am very confused because I only find old iText5 references or older, iText7 java references which, sometimes, I am not that able to "translate" to c#, etc.

I have tried setting a property to the Cell which contains the title and the page I want to go to.

I also looked some places that talked about having the content added from files. However, that is already done in my code, so I should directly deal with strings. Not even an array (or any similar), since I would be dealing string-by-string.

p.e: My program receives XML Value "Chapter 1" from a Node and it is automatically added to a String. So, I would add this string at the needed paragraph and in the TOC.

This is done because it is a REALLY complex XML file (848 lines in file, for example).

```
Paragraph indice = new Paragraph(new Text("Here the TOC line"));
Paragraph title = new Paragraph(new Text("Here the title"));
/*This goes at page 20. I am making further investigation so as to locate how should I look for the page (Looking for the string at the doc and getting the page, for example)*/

indice.SetProperty(Property.ACTION, PdfAction.CreateGoToR(@"C:\aplic\pdfPruebasIText\pdfPruebasIText\docPrueba.pdf", 20));

(Document) docPDF.add(indice);//TOC goes first
//More content
docPDF.add(title);//What I want indexed
```

I am adding more texts, paragraphs, tables etc at my docPrueba.pdf document. Just added what I thought are the main lines for my problem. If necessary, I would be adding more lines

In theory, it should go to page 20 of my Document docPrueba.pdf
Actually, it does nothing, except having the mouse pointer change its shape.

No error messages are shown, nor there is any error. Everything I added is generated, except this fail.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like actually the problem was that I was opening the document with internet browser instead of Adobe PDF software.

I am feeling ashamed about this...

I will answering again with the whole solution, since I think it would be useful for iText7 beginners like me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this thread: [iText7 Table of Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52604578/itext7-table-of-content)

I made code so that it is posible to add lines to the TOC while working at the document.

The main problem now is that the TOC is created AT THE END of the document (Whops!). So I am working on it for now to solve that issue.

For now, I will be adding my modified code here:

```
 string tit0 = "Titulo 0";//Title strings to add to a Dictionary
 string tit1 = "Titulo 1";
 string tit2 = "Titulo 2";

 Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, int>> indiceRelaciones = new Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

 indiceRelaciones=EscribirIndicePDF(innerDoc, DocPDF, tit0, indiceRelaciones);//HERE the title is added to the document and the dictionary flushed
 DocPDF.Add(parrafo1);//Paragraphs, tables and stuff
 DocPDF.Add(tabla1);
 DocPDF.Add(tabla2);
 indiceRelaciones = EscribirIndicePDF(innerDoc, DocPDF, tit1, indiceRelaciones);
 DocPDF.Add(parrafo2);
 indiceRelaciones = EscribirIndicePDF(innerDoc, DocPDF, tit2, indiceRelaciones);
 DocPDF.Add(parrafo3);

 crearIndice(innerDoc, DocPDF, indiceRelaciones);//This method generates the TOC
 DocPDF.Close();




 private static Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, int>> EscribirIndicePDF(PdfDocument innerDoc, Document docPDF, string tit, Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, int>> indice)
    {
        Paragraph titulo = new Paragraph().Add(new Text(tit));
        titulo.SetKeepTogether(true);
        outline = CreateOutline(outline, innerDoc, tit);
        KeyValuePair<string, int> paginaTitulo = new KeyValuePair<string, int>(tit, innerDoc.GetNumberOfPages());
        titulo.SetFontColor(ColorConstants.BLUE).SetDestination(tit).SetKeepWithNext(true).SetNextRenderer(new UpdatePageRenderer(titulo, paginaTitulo));
        docPDF.Add(titulo);
        indice.Add(tit, paginaTitulo);
        return indice;
    }


private static void crearIndice(PdfDocument innerDoc, Document docPDF, Dictionary<string, KeyValuePair<string, int>> indiceRelaciones)
    {//¡Este método crea en la primera página el índice! Este no se toca. Se modifica el otro para que se llame y se agreguen entradas al diccionario.
        List<TabStop> tabStops = new List<TabStop>();
        tabStops.Add(new TabStop(580, TabAlignment.RIGHT, new DottedLine()));
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, KeyValuePair<string, int>> entrada in indiceRelaciones) {
            KeyValuePair<string, int> texto = entrada.Value;
            string claveEntrada = entrada.Key;
            string claveTexto = texto.Key;
            string valorTexto = texto.Value.ToString();

            Paragraph p = new Paragraph().AddTabStops(tabStops).Add(claveTexto).Add(new Tab()).Add(valorTexto).SetAction(PdfAction.CreateGoTo(claveEntrada));
            docPDF.Add(p);
        }
    }


private static PdfOutline CreateOutline(PdfOutline outline, PdfDocument innerDoc, string line)
    {
        if (outline == null)
        {
            outline = innerDoc.GetOutlines(false);
            outline = outline.AddOutline(line);
            outline.AddDestination(PdfDestination.MakeDestination(new PdfString(line)));
            return outline;
        }

        PdfOutline hijo = outline.AddOutline(line);
        hijo.AddDestination(PdfDestination.MakeDestination(new PdfString(line)));
        return outline;
    }

    internal class UpdatePageRenderer : ParagraphRenderer
{
    private KeyValuePair<string, int> Entrada;

    public UpdatePageRenderer(Paragraph modelElement, KeyValuePair<string, int> entrada) : base(modelElement)
    {
        Entrada = entrada;
    }

    public override LayoutResult Layout(LayoutContext layoutContext)
    {
        LayoutResult result = base.Layout(layoutContext);
        int pagina = layoutContext.GetArea().GetPageNumber();

        Entrada = new KeyValuePair<string, int>(Entrada.Key, pagina);
        return result;
    }
}
```

I apologize for using spanish names. I will be editing this article for using english names, so everybody is able to understand the code.

And now...

I will try to get the TOC at the first page (as it should)